# how to make a property `Not Required` in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am new to asp.net MVC
some of the properties in My model especially property of type `int` become `required` by default without decorating it with `[Required]` attributes.however the problem is solved by making the filled nullable i.e `int? Some property`.
But i am not sure that this is the best approach or not... also i doubt if making a property `nullable` gonna make some problem later in code or not.
Any suggestion is highly appreciable.
Thanks in advance !!! :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making them nullable.  Why do you think there will be "problems"?

Comment: The way to go is `Nullable<T>` as you already use. There's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nullable is okay, but you need to take extra care when using values that could be null. The easiest is to use the coalesce null operator ??

```
var foo = myNullableField ?? new bar()
```

If the nullable field is, in fact null, foo will be assigned as a new object (in this example, you could use a default string, int, whatever). If it's not null it'll take the value from myNullableField

Answer (score 1):

Nullable is the preferable approach.  It's not sloppy.